# Assign list after join

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have a join statement in LINQ that combines 1 class and 1 List into a new class.

The class I want:

```
public class ClassResult
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Class2> Class2s {get;set;}
}
```

Class
1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

JOIN:

```
// Class1List is a List<Class1>
// Class2List is a List<Class2>

from class2 in class2List
join Class1 in Class1List on class2.ID equals Class1.ID    

select new ClassResult 
{
    Name = Class1.Name,
    ClassResult = ? ? ?    
};
```

How can I get the `List<Class2>` of all the `Class2` elements that have the same `ID` as `Class1`? And how do I assign it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `Class1List ` and what is `Class2List`?

Comment: A List<Class1> and List<Class2>

Comment: So please show how the `Class1` looks like

Comment: Looks like you want to `group class2 by Class1 into grp`.  Then in the select `Name = grp.Key.Name` and `ClassResult = grp.ToList()`

Comment: edited, did not think that it was of importance so I left it out - my apologies.

Comment: The second property in `ClassResult` is missing it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is a bit difficult to understand with the current input I think what you are asking for is `GroupJoin`:

```
from c1 in Class1List
join c2 in Class2List on c1.ID equals c2.ID into g
select new ClassResult
{
    Name = c1.Name,
    Class2 = g.ToList()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed. I used an input like this so its easier to understand as the classes are quite long and I just wanted to know how to do it in theory.

Comment: @user3024750 - That is fine :) I just needed to properly understand the relationship between the 3 classes. As you see I assumed this is what you meant but it is always good to have it in the question itself